# debug web workers in node js using visual studio 2015

Tags: node.js

I'm using webworker-threads package in my node js application. when I set a breakpoint in Worker callback function. I doesn't stops and debugs it just ignores it, I am using visual studio 2015. I couldn't find any solution to this on internet

Comment: Have you tried to use `debugger` keyword?

Comment: yes and nothing happens it just skips